# rails brakeman order sql injection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, brakeman

How can I avoid a brakeman warning in Rails when constructing an order method from parameters?

```rb
def index
  @methods = [:name, :manager, :deadline]
  assignments = Assignment.order(sort_column(@methods) + " " + sort_direction).received(current_user).root
end

def sort_column(column_names)
  column_names.each do |column|
    return column if column == params[:sort]
  end
  return 'updated_at'
end

def sort_direction
  params[:direction] == 'asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc'
end
```

I'm working hard to avoid ever putting user-generated code directly into the query, but brakeman still alerts (medium confidence) that this is a SQL injection vulnerability.

Is this a false positive? If not, how do I correct the vulnerability?

If so, is there an easy way to avoid the false positive?

Comment: Looks like a false positive to me, it is probably freaking out about the string operations in the `order` call. What happens if you replace `sort_column(@methods) + " " + sort_direction` with a single method call?

Comment: What mu said. It's a false positive and it's because you are manually building the string. Actually, even removing the `" "` will make the warning go away.

Comment: Unfortunately `"#{sort_column(@methods)} #{sort_direction}"` doesn't prevent the false positive.

Comment: Neither does creating a private method in the controller and calling the private method to construct the string. Brakeman seems to be too smart to be fooled by shifting things around, but not smart enough to explain how I can deal with this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, this is too long for a comment.

From my testing, moving the string building into a method like this does make the warning go away:

```
def index
  @methods = [:name, :manager, :deadline]
  assignments = Assignment.order(sort_order).received(current_user).root
end

def sort_order
  sort_column(@methods) + " " + sort_direction
end
```

However, that's just hiding the problem. I would suggest adding something like this to the `Assignment` model instead:

```
class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.sorted_by(column, direction)
    direction = direction.downcase == 'asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc'
    column = sanitize_sql(column)
    order("#{column} #{direction}")
  end

end
```

Just keep in mind that sometimes you have to choose between keeping a tool happy and keeping your code reasonable. As for the false positive, I don't see this particular issue being resolved, since it is not simple to inspect `sort_column` and know it is safe.

Answer (score 3):

You could add a sanitize method on the order by clause

```
 assignments = Assignment.order(ActiveRecord::Base::sanitize(sort_column(@methods) + " " + sort_direction)).received(current_user).root
```

Comment: I thought this worked, but it turns out to simply negate the order method. Brakeman likes it and stops issuing alerts, but the sanitization appears to break the ordering. Weirdly, it doesn't error. It just stops ordering silently.

Comment: Well... that's interesting. Before sanitizing the order by clause looks like `"name asc"` and after sanitizing it becomes `"'name asc'"`. The quotes being added are apparently causing the query not to work.